# '[onTurnError] unhandled error: TypeError: this.storage.read is not a function'

Tags: node.js, botframework

Buiding a bot with Node and JavaScript and connecting to an Azure Blob Storage:

```js
const { BlobStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');
var optionsBlob = {
    containerName: 'messages', 
    storageAccountOrConnectionString: <secret>
};
```

Following the exact code from npm's [Basic Usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-azure#use) and getting this error when I run `node start`

```
[onTurnError] unhandled error: TypeError: this.storage.read is not a function
```

My dependencies are all installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "~4.6.2",
    "botbuilder-azure": "^4.6.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "restify": "~8.4.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I was not passing the storage instance to the state managers.

```js
const { BlobStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');

var options = {
    containerName: 'messages', 
    storageAccountOrConnectionString: process.env.STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING, 
};

const blobStorage = new BlobStorage(options);

// I was not passing the correct object to the state manager
// Make sure you pass it here
const userState = new UserState(blobStorage);
const conversationState = new ConversationState(blobStorage);
```